# React Requests with Router in function

Tags: reactjs, forms, request, router

Hi I am working on using react router after a request post and am having some problems.

```
handleSubmit = event => {
event.preventDefault();
request.post(
  {
    url: 'http://localhost:8080/usernamepassword',
    json: true,
    body: {
      email: this.state.email,
      password: this.state.password
    }
  },
  function(err, httpResponse, body) {
    console.log(err);
    console.log(httpResponse);
    console.log(body);

    if (err) {
        this.props.history.push('/nosuccess');
    } else {
        this.props.history.push('/success');
    }
  }
);
```

The problem is with

```
    if (err) {
        this.props.history.push('/nosuccess');
    } else {
        this.props.history.push('/success');
    }
```

I know (atleast i think) that the problem is with the this.props is not being passed through.

The full code is below. I am working on putting the request into an arrow function (from @webdevdani). Learning that right now.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import request from 'request';
import {Link, withRouter} from 'react-router-dom';
import '../Form.css';

class SignIn extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            username: '',
            password: ''
        };
    }

    handleChange = event => {
        this.setState({
            [event.target.id]: event.target.value
        });
    };

    handleSubmit = event => {
        event.preventDefault();

        request.post(
            {
                url: 'http://localhost:8080/signin',
                json: true,
                body: {
                    username: this.state.username,
                    password: this.state.password
                }
            },
            function (err, httpResponse, body) {
                console.log(err);
                console.log(httpResponse);
                console.log(body);
                if (err) {
                    this.props.history.push('/nosuccess');
                } else {
                    this.props.history.push('/success');

                }
            }
        );
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <form id="login" className="form-content" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                    <h1 className="form-content-text-h1"> Sign In</h1>
                    <div className="padding10">
                        <div className="form-content-text-textbox"> EDIPI (DoD ID):</div>
                        <input type="text" className="input1" id="username" onChange={this.handleChange} required/>
                        <br/>
                        <br/>
                        <div className="form-content-text-textbox"> Password:</div>
                        <input type="password" className="input1" id="password" onChange={this.handleChange} required/>
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" className="button1">
                        Sign In
                    </button>
                    <br/>

                    <Link to="/resetpassword" style={{textDecorationColor: '#26c6da'}}>
                        <h1 className="form-content-link-text">Sign In Assistance</h1>
                    </Link>

                    <br/>
                    <br/>

                    <h1 className="form-content-text-h1"> New Users </h1>

                    <Link to="/register">
                        <button className="button1" type="submit">
                            Register
                        </button>
                    </Link>
                </form>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default withRouter(SignIn);
```

Here is the full code.

Comment: What do you try to post and why? Can you give us a bit more code, also how your component and React Router is wired up please?

Comment: its a login page. I post the user name and password to a backend server. Added the full code of SignIn.js @GeraltDieSocke

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the value of 'this' is not what you're expecting. If you change your function declaration in the `request.post` arguments to be an arrow function, it should have the 'this' value of your component. Then you'll have access to `this.props`

Comment: Hmmm. I just console.log(this) before and in the request function. They are different. The this in the function is related to the post request.

Comment: Right. You want to change it so the scope of the new function is the component's scope